# UIView transition animation does not work with transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion method

Tags: ios4, uiviewanimationtransition

In iOS Documentation usage of beginAnimation-commitAnimation is discouraged. So for animations and transitions there are new methods that make use of ^blocks. However when I use transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion method I get no transition effects.So if I write:

```c
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];

firstView.hidden = YES;
secondView.hidden = NO;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

it works but if I do it the following way

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1.0 options 
      UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
        animations:^{
          firstView.hidden = YES;
          secondView.hidden = NO;
         } completion:NULL
         ];
```

I do not get any transition effects. What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, I've found the subtle detail everyone needs to take note of in order to get the animation and transitions work with the method available in iOS 4 and later.When specifying the animation/transition options for the method we must use the constants with the word "Option" in it. So instead of writing

```
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
```

we should write

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
```

after fixing that the transition worked just fine

Comment: Ha, nice spot, and easy mistake to make with autocompletion... where is type safety when you need it!

Comment: Oh my GOD! I spent two frustrating hours on this crap until I found this. Apple seriously needs to depreciate the "non-option" versions.

Comment: As a result I decided to set the build setting `CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION ` to `YES` from now on.